# PySpark. Passing a Dataframe to a pandas_udf and returning a series

Tags: python, pandas, apache-spark, pyspark

I'm using PySpark's new `pandas_udf` decorator and I'm trying to get it to take multiple columns as an input and return a series as an input, however, I get a `TypeError: Invalid argument`

Example code

```
@pandas_udf(df.schema, PandasUDFType.SCALAR)
def fun_function(df_in):
    df_in.loc[df_in['a'] < 0] = 0.0
    return (df_in['a'] - df_in['b']) / df_in['c']
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[A SCALAR udf](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.pandas_udf) expects pandas series as input instead of a data frame. For your case, there's no need to use a udf. Direct calculation from columns `a`, `b`, `c` after clipping should work:

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as f

df = spark.createDataFrame([[1,2,4],[-1,2,2]], ['a', 'b', 'c'])

clip = lambda x: f.when(df.a < 0, 0).otherwise(x)
df.withColumn('d', (clip(df.a) - clip(df.b)) / clip(df.c)).show()

#+---+---+---+-----+
#|  a|  b|  c|    d|
#+---+---+---+-----+
#|  1|  2|  4|-0.25|
#| -1|  2|  2| null|
#+---+---+---+-----+
```

And if you have to use a `pandas_udf`, your return type needs to be `double`, not `df.schema` because *you only return a pandas series not a pandas data frame*; And also you need to pass columns as Series into the function not the whole data frame:

```
@pandas_udf('double', PandasUDFType.SCALAR)
def fun_function(a, b, c):
    clip = lambda x: x.where(a >= 0, 0)
    return (clip(a) - clip(b)) / clip(c)

df.withColumn('d', fun_function(df.a, df.b, df.c)).show()
#+---+---+---+-----+                                                             
#|  a|  b|  c|    d|
#+---+---+---+-----+
#|  1|  2|  4|-0.25|
#| -1|  2|  2| null|
#+---+---+---+-----+
```

Comment: TypeError: pandas udf only takes one argument

Comment: Check your pandas and pyarrow's version, I can get the result successfully.@mat77